# make a css file create on the fly and dynamicly

Tags: css, dynamic

There are many situations when you have to create a css file dynamically.
For example you may want to change the font family to something base on the parameter in the request

You can make the css build dynamically base on a parameter pass to it, and make a css file to a dynamic asp, jsp, php ...

For example in java:

```
<link href="MainCss.jsp?param=someFont" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then is the MainCss.jsp

```
body {
font-size:100%;
background:#fff;

<%if ( request.getParameter("param") == "someFon" )%>
  font-family:"Tahoma";
<%else%>
  font-family:"Verdana";

}
```

I have been told that there are many disadvantages in this solution:

- It does not allow caching of the CSS files on the server and client
- It makes it more difficult to understand and maintain the pages
- Each time your server will serves a CSS page, it will have to run a few tens of thousands of additional CPU cycles, compared to having the CSS files as purestatic documents.

They suggestion seems to be acceptable!

But, I keep looking around the web and find many sites which somehow do something like above:
ebay.com:

```
<link href="http://gh.ebaystatic.com/header/css/all.min?combo=11&ds=3&siteid=0" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

wikipedia.org

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php?debug=false&amp;lang=en&amp;modules=ext.gad" />
```

They have told me that these site also use pure css and the `load.php?debuge=false`... is only a css file selector and will select a pure css file from harddisk and send it to the client.

Is this technique correct? 
Has any one had any experience with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of possibilities:

- A CSS file could be generated and stored in server's file system to take advantage of caching.
- You can generate CSS on parametrized GET request. In such case browser will typically cache the response, but the very first time each browser will make CSS be processed on server side. By the way, if you look at ASP.NET technology you will find there things named "Themes" which include sets of various CSS files and server-side attributes. They are processed at server side and Microsoft doesn't seem to feel sad about it.
- You can prepare a bunch of CSS classes in your static CSS file (I beleive that number of fonts isn't so great that you can't fill a CSS file). At least the class attribute allows to use multiple values.